# Date Function SAS

Tags: sas

Using 'intck' for calculating no of days between two dates.

```
data test;
x=intck('day','01dec2016'd,'31dec2016'd);
run;
```

Output is x=30.
It should be 31.How to solve it ?`

Comment: Why do you think the output should be 31?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way!

```
data test;
  x=intck('day','01dec2016'd,'31dec2016'd)+1;
run;
```

as @jonrsharpe comments.. There are indeed 30 days between those dates, so if you are looking for the number of days in a month, you can try starting from the last day of the previous month - or simply add one.